# Non-unique solutions to PDE of first order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Given a quasi-linear PDE $u_x+yu_y=u$ with initial condition $u(p,0)=e^p$.

Of course, we use characteristic line method:

$x_t(t,s)=1$, $y_t(t,s)=y$, $u_t(t,s)=u$

$\Rightarrow x(t,s)=t+C_1(s), y(t,s)=C_2(s)e^t, u(t,s)=C_3(s)e^t$

Plug-in the initial condition: $x(0,s)=C(s):=s$, then $y(0,s)=C_2(s)=0$, $u(0,s)=C_3(s)=e^s$

Put all together, $x=t+s, u=e^{t+s}\Rightarrow u(x,y)=e^x$.

Although it does not satisfy the unique solution condition, i.e. parametrization of $x,y$ by $t,s$ is not regular, each step of derivation for me makes sense. So eventually the solution must be only that one.

However, $e^x+y$ is a solution (I found it by seeing...)

So what was wrong? Where can one get more solutitons? And how? Not just by guessing.

Answer (score 2):

$$u_x+yu_y=u$$
$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{u}$

First family of characteristic curves, from $\quad\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{y} \quad\to\quad ye^{-x}=c_1$

Second family of characteristic curves, from $\quad\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{du}{u} \quad\to\quad ue^{-x}=c_2$

General solution of the PDE : $\quad ue^{-x}=F\left(ye^{-x}\right)$
$$u(x,y)=e^xF\left(ye^{-x}\right)$$
$F$ is any function.

Condition :

$u(x,0)=e^x=e^xF\left(0e^{-x}\right)=e^xF(0) \quad\implies\quad F(0)=1$

Solution of the PDE with the condition :
$$u(x,y)=e^xF\left(ye^{-x}\right)$$
where $F$ is no longer any function, but is any function which is equal to $1$ when $x=0$.

Since they are an infinity of functions $F(x)$ satisfying $F(0)=1$, the problem has an infinity of solutions.

For examples :

With $\quad F(X)=1+X\quad$ the particular solution is  : $\quad u(x,y)=e^x\left(1+ye^{-x}\right)=e^x+y$

With $\quad F(X)=1+X^2\quad$ the particular solution is : $\quad u(x,y)=e^x\left(1+ye^{-x}\right)^2$

With $\quad F(X)=\cos(X)\quad$ the particular solution is  : $\quad u(x,y)=e^x\cos\left(ye^{-x}\right)$

And so on : An infinity of such examples can be found.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has infinitely many solutions (no unique solution) since the initial curve $\bigg (x=t,\,y=0,\,u=e^t\bigg)$is a characteristic curve. More precisely, the Cauchy problem is defined on the characteristic curve.

From your characterictic equations you have $\frac{du}{u}=\frac{dx}{1}\Rightarrow ue^{-x}=c_1$ and $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{y}\Rightarrow ye^{-x}=c_2$. Thus the general solution can be written in the form $$c_1=f(c_2),$$
 that is, $$ue^{-x}=f(ye^{-x}),$$ where $f$ is any $C^1$-function. When you substitute $x=t, y=0$, and  $u=e^t$, you see that $f(0)=1$. This means that there are infinitely many such $f$ satisfying the problem and $2x+1, \cos x, x^2+1,\, e^x,$..etc. are some examples of functions satisfying $f(0)=1$.

The problem has no unique solution. If it were so, $u_x$ and $u_y$ could be  solved uniquely on the curve $\Gamma: x=t, y=0, u=e^t$.

on $\Gamma$ the derivative of $u$ is $\frac{du}{dt}=u_x\frac{du}{dt}+u_y\frac{dy}{dt}\Longrightarrow e^t=u_x+0\Rightarrow u_x=e^t$

Looking at the PDE on $\Gamma$ we get $u_x=e^t$. We can find $u_x$ , but where is $u_y$? It can be anything, so it cannot be obtained uniquely. Therefore the problem has no unique solution.

Comment: Thx! Why when along the curve, it will get weird? But if you see my derivations after plug-in the initial condition, I think each step is ''if and and only if''. If I just ignore $y$, eventually, $u$ is given explicitly just by $x$..

Comment: @Junui: you cannot ignore $y$ because $u$ is a function of $x$ and $y$. Also it is not a quasilinear but just a linear equation.

Comment: I might think u is constant on y? Say arbitrarily $u(x,y,z,w,s)$, given $2u+2\sin x\cos x=3u$, so I get $u=\sin 2x$. I think the case was the same: $x=s+t, u=e^{t+s}$, no matter what $y$ is we must have $u=e^x$.

Comment: $u=e^x$ is a solution among all infinite number of solutions. In order to have a unique solution $u_x$ and $u_y$ can be solved uniquely on the given curve: $x=t,\, y=0,\,u=e^t$.

Comment: I added the reoson to the answer why the problem has no unique solution.