# Solve $u_x+yu_y=u$ where $u=u(x,y)$ with $u(x,0)=e^x$ and $u(0,y)=y^2$

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, characteristics

Solve the following PDE $u_x+yu_y=u$ where $u=u(x,y)$

with

- 1)$u(x,0)=e^x$, explain why several solutions are available.
- 2) $u(0,y)=y^2$

---

Here is what I did: 
1) $$x_t=1, y_t=y, \ u_t=u$$ $$x(0,s)=s, \ y(0,s)=0, \ u(0,s)=e^s$$

Solving that, we get $x=t+s, \ y=e^t-1, \ u=e^te^s$ i.e. $t=x-s$ thus $u=e^{x-s}e^s=e^x$

2) $$x_t=1, y_t=y, \ u_t=u$$ $$x(0,s)=0, \ y(0,s)=s, \ u(0,s)=s^2$$

Solving that, we get $x=t, \ y=e^t+s, \ u=e^ts^2$ i.e. $t=x, s=y-e^x$ thus $u=e^{x}(y-e^x)^2$

---

My questions are: 
1) Is my work correct ? 
2) Why would several solutions be available for $u(x,0)$ ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: In case $(1)$ there are infinitely many solutions of the form $$u(x,y)=e^x+Cy$$

Comment: @PeterForeman But why exactly ? I mean, how am I supposed to see that ?

Comment: I assumed that there was a solution of the form $e^x+f(y)$ where $f(0)=0$ and solved the PDE by plugging this solution into the ordinal equation.

Comment: @PeterForeman But how am I supposed to notice that ?

Comment: I don't know what you want me to say. That is how I found the solution.

Comment: @PeterForeman So the person solving this problem is somehow supposed to notice that the solutions are of the form $e^x+f(y)$ to realise that there are infinitely many solutions, is that right ? (nothing ironical, I'm just trying to be sure that it's what you mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is almost identical to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2567239/non-unique-solutions-to-pde-of-first-order/2567579#2567579). Since it isn't an exact duplicate, I will repeat the same analysis made in the answer by JJacquelin.

$$u_x+yu_y=u$$
Set of characteristic ODEs: $\quad \frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{u}$

First family of characteristic curves, from $\quad\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{y} \quad\to\quad ye^{-x}=c_1$

Second family of characteristic curves, from $\quad\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{du}{u} \quad\to\quad ue^{-x}=c_2$

General solution of the PDE : $\quad ue^{-x}=F\left(ye^{-x}\right)$
$$u(x,y)=e^xF\left(ye^{-x}\right)$$
$F$ is any function.

Condition 1: $\quad u(x,0)=e^x$.

$u(x,0)=e^x=e^xF\left(0e^{-x}\right)=e^xF(0) \quad\implies\quad F(0)=1$

Solution of the PDE with the condition :
$$u(x,y)=e^xF\left(ye^{-x}\right)$$
where $F$ is no longer any function, but is any function which is equal to $1$ when $x=0$.

Since they are an infinity of functions $F(x)$ satisfying $F(0)=1$, the problem has an infinity of solutions.

For examples :

With $\quad F(X)=1+X\quad$ the particular solution is  : $\quad u(x,y)=e^x\left(1+ye^{-x}\right)=e^x+y$

With $\quad F(X)=1+X^2\quad$ the particular solution is : $\quad u(x,y)=e^x\left(1+ye^{-x}\right)^2$

With $\quad F(X)=\cos(X)\quad$ the particular solution is  : $\quad u(x,y)=e^x\cos\left(ye^{-x}\right)$

And so on : An infinity of such examples can be found.

---

Third family of characteristics curves, from $\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{u} \quad\to\quad \frac{u}{y}=c_3$

General solution, with any differentiable function $F$:
$$\frac{u}{y}=F(ye^{-x}) \quad\to\quad u=y\:F(ye^{-x}) $$

Condition 2: $\quad u(0,y)=y^2$.

$\quad u(0,y)=y^2=y\:F(ye^{0})=y\:F(y) \quad$ determines the function $F$ :

$$F(t)=t \quad \text{for any } t$$

Bringing this function $F$ into the above general solution gives

$$u(x,y)=y^2\:e^{-x}$$